# GWT on OSX, what do I need to know?

Tags: gwt

I'm about to start GWT on OSX. I come from a typical Textmate/RoR background. Is there anything I should be aware of? Is OSX a bad envrionment to be doing GWT developmenet in?

Answer (score 2):

OSX is a fine environment for developing GWT. I would strongly suggest you use Eclipse, with [Google's Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/eclipse/) which has really nice support for including the GWT SDK, and handling GWT-specific syntax (like native code blocks).

Answer (score 2):

I've been developing GWT apps on OSX for some time now, and I've tried both IntelliJ and Eclipse. Eclipse is my environment of choice because all of Google's plugins are built for it, and it's an IDE I'm familiar with from my pre-GWT days. (As an added bonus, I can use the same IDE for Android development with no hassle.) Having come from a Windows-based development environment prior to moving to OSX, I can't say I miss it. OSX is faster, more stable, more responsive, and simply better for software development IMO.

I think if you're in a position to start GWT development on either a PC or Mac, you should definitely go with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

[Intellij](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gwt.html) also does a good job. I had to switch a year ago because eclipse would almost bring my mac book to a screeching halt (macbook pro, the best on the market at the time). Intellij would run with half the memory on the same machine.

OSX a bad dev enviroment?! Ever been to a dev conference? Look around next time, the only conf with more PCs than Macs is a windows dev conference :)